# How can we simplify equivalent sums over different index variables?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

The following should be `True` for any function `x`:

```
Sum[x[i], {i, 2, n - 1}] == Sum[x[j], {j, 2, n - 1}]
```

`Reduce` and `Simplify` do not seem to recognize this.

Is there an appropriate way to get Wolfram Language to reduce this to `True`?

Comment: It's interesting that `Sum[x[i], {i, 1, 1000}] == Sum[x[j], {j, 1, 1000}]` returns True.

Comment: The simplest way is using `expression /. i->j`

Comment: @bills this is because providing an upper limit results in the explicit evaluation of the summing returning `x[1]+x[2]+...+x[1000]` in both cases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we can read in ["Details and Options" of `Sum` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html#24230):

> The iteration variable *i* is treated as local, effectively using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html).

So index of summation is dynamically scoped, thus `Sum[x[i], {i, 2, n - 1}]` can give different result than `Sum[x[j], {j, 2, n - 1}]` if `i` or `j` is present in body of `x` function, e.g.:

```
ClearAll[x, i]
x[arg_] := arg + i

Sum[x[i], {i, 2, n - 1}]
(* -2 - n + n^2 *)

Sum[x[j], {j, 2, n - 1}]
(* 1/2 (-2 - 4 i - n + 2 i n + n^2) *)
```

If we want to be sure that summation index will not interfere with any symbols coming from evaluation of `x[i]` we should manually localize summation indices using lexical scoping construct: [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html):

```
Module[{i}, Sum[x[i], {i, 2, n - 1}]]
(* 1/2 (-2 - 4 i - n + 2 i n + n^2) *)

Module[{j}, Sum[x[j], {j, 2, n - 1}]]
(* 1/2 (-2 - 4 i - n + 2 i n + n^2) *)
```

but this will not help with equation simplifications.

---

### `Sum` normalization

To help *Mathematica* in simplifying expressions involving `Sum` we can manually "normalize" sums by renaming summation indices and shifting summation bounds. Following implementation renames variables lexically present in `Sum` expression, so it automatically ensures lexical scoping for renamed variables, similarly as `Module` in above examples. In some situations this may be unwanted, so make sure to understand difference between dynamic and lexical scoping, in this context, before using following functions.

`NormalizeSum` function will replace consecutive dummy variables in `Sum` expressions with `SummationIndex[1]`, `SummationIndex[2]`, etc. which will be formatted as `i₁`, `i₂`, ...

Lower summation bound, if finite will be shifted to value of `"DefaultBound"` option (by default `0`), otherwise upper bound, if finite, will be shifted to default bound, if nothing is known about finiteness of both bounds they are not shifted.

```
BeginPackage["SumNormalization`"];
Unprotect["`*"];
ClearAll["`*"]

NormalizeSum::usage = "NormalizeSum[expr] \
normalizes dummy sumation indices in Sum expressions present in expr. \
i-th dummy index is renamed to SummationIndex[i], \
summation bounds are shifted such that, \
if lower bound is finite, then new lower bound is zero, \
otherwise if upper bound is finite, then new upper bound is zero.";

SummationIndex::usage = "SummationIndex[i] \
represents i-th dummy summation index in Sum expression.";

Begin["`Private`"];
ClearAll["`*"]

finiteQ[_DirectedInfinity] = False;
finiteQ[x_] := TrueQ@Refine[x != ComplexInfinity]

shiftBounds[i_, min_?finiteQ, max_, default_] :=
    {i + min - default, default, max - min + default}
shiftBounds[i_, min_, max_?finiteQ, default_] :=
    {i + max - default, min - max + default, default}
shiftBounds[i_, min_, max_, _] := {i, min, max}

NormalizeSum // Options = {"DefaultBound" -> 0};
NormalizeSum[expr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := expr /.
    (h : Sum | Inactive[Sum])[x_, iterators__, sumOpts : OptionsPattern[]] :>
        Module[
            {
                default = OptionValue[NormalizeSum, opts, "DefaultBound"],
                assumpt = OptionValue[Sum, sumOpts, Assumptions],
                rules = {}, usedIndices = {}, heldIterators
            },
            heldIterators = Join @@ Replace[Unevaluated@{iterators}, {
                {i_, min_:1, max_} :>
                    RuleCondition@Module[{newIndex, newMin, newMax, replIndex},
                        newIndex = SummationIndex[Length@rules +1];
                        {newMin, newMax} = Unevaluated@{min, max} /. rules;
                        {replIndex, newMin, newMax} =
                            Assuming[
                                assumpt && Element[usedIndices, Complexes],
                                shiftBounds[newIndex, newMin, newMax, default]
                            ];
                        AppendTo[usedIndices, newIndex];
                        AppendTo[rules, HoldPattern@i -> replIndex];
                        Hold@Evaluate@{newIndex, newMin, newMax}
                    ],
                i_ :> Hold@i
            }, {1}];
            h @@ (Join[Hold[x] /. rules, heldIterators, Hold[sumOpts]])
        ]
call : NormalizeSum[__, nonOpt : Except@OptionsPattern[], OptionsPattern[]] /;
    Message[NormalizeSum::nonopt,
        HoldForm@nonOpt, HoldForm@1, HoldForm@call
    ] :=
        "NeverReached"
NormalizeSum[] /;
    Message[NormalizeSum::argx, HoldForm@NormalizeSum, HoldForm@0] :=
        "NeverReached"
NormalizeSum // SyntaxInformation =
    {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]}};
NormalizeSum // Protect;

$summationIndexDisplayFunction = StyleBox[SubscriptBox["i", #], Italic]&;

SummationIndex /: MakeBoxes[
    index : SummationIndex[i_Integer?Positive],
    form : StandardForm | TraditionalForm
] :=
    TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[i, form]}, "SummationIndex",
        DisplayFunction -> $summationIndexDisplayFunction,
        InterpretationFunction -> (RowBox[{"SummationIndex", "[", #, "]"}]&)
    ]
call : SummationIndex@Except[i_Integer?Positive] /;
    Message[SummationIndex::intp, HoldForm@call, HoldForm@1] :=
        "NeverReached"
SummationIndex[args : PatternSequence[] | PatternSequence[_, __]] /;
    Message[SummationIndex::argx,
        HoldForm@SummationIndex, HoldForm@Evaluate@Length@Hold[args]] :=
            "NeverReached"
SummationIndex // SyntaxInformation = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_}};

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Example of sum with one non-dummy index `j` and three dummy indices: `i` with both bounds symbolic, and `k` with upper symbolic bound and implicit lower bound, by default equal to `1`, and `l` with lower bound depending on other index `i`. We assign values to indices to make sure there's no evaluation leak. Sum is normalized assuming that lower symbolic bound is an integer (thus it's finite).

```
ClearAll[f, i, j, k, n, m, o]
i = 100; j = 200; k = 300; l = 400;

Sum[f[i] j + k, {i, m, n}, j, {k, o}, {l, i, p}]
(* Sum[k + j*f[i], {i, m, n}, j, {k, o}, {l, i, p}] *)

Assuming[n \[Element] Integers, % // NormalizeSum]
(* Sum[1 + j*f[n + SummationIndex[1]] + SummationIndex[2],
   {SummationIndex[1], m - n, 0}, j, {SummationIndex[2], 0, -1 + o},
   {SummationIndex[3], 0, -n + p - SummationIndex[1]}] *)

(* Use some example numeric values of bounds to check that un-normalized and normalized sums represent same mathematical expression. *)
{%%, %} /. {m -> 9, n -> 11, o -> 2, p -> 12}
(* {800 (3 + 199 f[9]) + 600 (3 + 199 f[10]) + 400 (3 + 199 f[11]),
    800 (3 + 199 f[9]) + 600 (3 + 199 f[10]) + 400 (3 + 199 f[11])} *)

SameQ @@ %
(* True *)
```

[image: Normalized Sums]

Now back to original problem:

```
ClearAll[x, n]
Sum[x[i], {i, 2, n - 1}] == Sum[x[j], {j, 2, n - 1}] // NormalizeSum
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very naive attempt to do this (thanks to [Xavier's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125976/how-can-we-simplify-equivalent-sums-over-different-index-variables/125977?noredirect=1#comment340998_125977) for the suggestion of using a local variable to handle more general cases):

```
ClearAll[sumsEqualQ]
sumsEqualQ[
  Sum[expr1_, {iterVar1_, min1_, max1_}],
  Sum[expr2_, {iterVar2_, min2_, max2_}]
  ] := Module[{iter, exprsEqual},
  exprsEqual = (expr1 /. iterVar1 -> iter) === (expr2 /. 
      iterVar2 -> iter);
  Which[
   (* same expressions, same boundaries *)
   exprsEqual && min1 === min2 && max1 === max2,
   True,
   (* same expressions, different boundaries *)
   exprsEqual && (min1 =!= min2 || max1 =!= max2),
   False,
   (* different expressions *)
   ! exprsEqual,
   False
   ]
  ]
```

which correctly gives

```
In[78]:= sumsEqualQ[
 Sum[x[i], {i, 2, n - 1}],
 Sum[x[j], {j, 2, n - 1}]
 ]

Out[78]= True

In[127]:= sumsEqualQ[
 Sum[x[i], {i, 2, n - 1}],
 Sum[y[j], {j, 2, n - 1}]
 ]

Out[127]= False

In[130]:= sumsEqualQ[
 Sum[i x[i], {i, 2, n - 1}],
 Sum[i y[j], {j, 2, n - 1}]
 ]

Out[130]= False

sumsEqualQ[
 Sum[x[i], {i, 2, n - 1}],
 Sum[x[j], {j, 2, n}]
 ]

False
```

Comment: `sumsEqualQ[Sum[x[i], {i, 2, n - 1}], Sum[x[j], {j, 2, n}]]` yields `True`.

Comment: @corey979 edited accordingly, thanks for pointing out. Even now the output will of course be wrong taking just slightly more complicated cases. For example `Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]` will result different from `Sum[x[i+1],{i,0,n-1}]`. To properly handle all of such instances (not just this example I mean) would be quite a non-trivial task, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

If the function is defined, then the two sums are identified as equal. Here are five variations, three are pure functions and two are regular (impure) function. All return `True`:

```
Sum[Function[u, 3 + u^2][i], {i, 2, n - 1}] == 
   Sum[Function[v, 3 + v^2][j], {j, 2, n - 1}]

Sum[(3 + #) &, {i, 2, n - 1}] == Sum[(3 + #) &, {j, 2, n - 1}]

f = (3 + #) &;
Sum[f[i], {i, 2, n - 1}] == Sum[f[j], {j, 2, n - 1}]

g[n_] := 5*n^2 - Log[n];
Sum[g[i], {i, 2, n - 1}] == Sum[g[j], {j, 2, n - 1}]

h[n_] := Sqrt[n];
Sum[h[i], {i, -n, n}] == Sum[h[j], {j, -n, n}]
```

The final one might be a little overzealous in returning `True`, since the `Sqrt` is multiply defined.

Comment: Note that in all your examples *Mathematica* is smart enough to calculate the sum and give explicit symbolic answer, so you're not really comparing `Sum` expressions. If we use slightly more complicated function, then equality will remain unevaluated: `f = Floor@*Log;
Sum[f[i], {i, 1, n}] == Sum[f[j], {j, 1, n}]`