# Why cant this sum expand to zero?

Tags: symbolic, summation

[image]

why cant this sum expand, and get the result zero? I want to prove something with symbolic equations in mathematica, but there seem to be not many tuturials about this area.

```
Simplify[Sum[Subscript[x, j], {j, 1, K}] - 
   Sum[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, K}]]
```

Comment: it is a little hard to copy code from an image. Better to paste plain text version.

Comment: sorry，I made it complicated, I'll modify it

Comment: It is better to use the `InputForm` version. i.e. do `InputForm[expression]` or `InputForm[%]`  and after that, copy and paste here the output cell generated in your notebook. This will eliminate all those hard to read funny looking boxes and slashes.

Comment: thank you, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I think this was asked before. Please see if this answers your question [how-can-we-simplify-equivalent-sums-over-different-index-variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125976/how-can-we-simplify-equivalent-sums-over-different-index-variables)  Mathematica needs little help with this.